# Can you 2 gang 240v receptacles

Tags: electrical, wiring, 240v

I have 220 running to my irrigation pump drawing from my pond.  I want to add aeration.  Can I gang 220?

Comment: What size is this 220 circuit?

Comment: 40 Amp, 2-20's.  I can change if needed.  I've got one 1/2 horse water pump and another 1/4 horse compressor that will run together for only a couple hours a day together.  The compressor will run 24/7,

Comment: Sorry, new to site.  Didn't see you asked a question.

Comment: Do you mean a 40A/240V circuit, or a 20A/240V circuit?  (Just look at the number on the breaker and tell it to me directly)

Comment: its a double 20.

Comment: What is present currently for a receptacle, or is the pump hardwired right now?

Comment: Currently one receptacle for pump.  Want to add another for aerator.

Comment: The existing receptacle is a single NEMA 6-15 or 6-20 receptacle, correct?  (The NEMA 6 looks like the NEMA 5, only it's blinking at you ;)

Comment: existing winks.  New one for the aerator doesn't.

Comment: Imgur is simple -- just go to the site, hit the green "New post" button at the top, and drag the picture to the box that pops up -- you can then copy and paste the URL of the page that loads into a comment here

Comment: ok, imgur not responding.  I looked them up and existing is Nema 6-20 and new one is Nema 6-15.

Comment: Instructions for adding photographs to your posts are at https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/523/how-can-i-add-an-image-to-a-question-answer As a new user, you'll only be able to add two so please make sure they show all the information that has been asked for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If it is 15A or 20A, You can have as many 220V outlets as you want, single or double receptacle.   Except you cannot have them in certain rooms of a home.

You can use 15A receptacles on a 20A circuit, as long as there is more than one receptacle in the circuit.

So just change this [image] to this [image] and done.

Comment: How do you gang them?

Comment: They're outside at the irrigation pump site.

Comment: @TomSouthwell See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Turn the power off at the breaker, unplug the pump, and replace the existing single 6-20 receptacle with a duplex 6-20 T-slot receptacle, such as the Hubbell HBL5462, Leviton 5462, or equivalent -- remember when wiring the receptacle that it goes black-to-brass, white-to-silver, and bare/green-to-green.  Since these are outdoor receptacles, putting an extra-duty while-in-use cover on the box would be a wise idea at the time, as well.